# Is this function identically zero??

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Let D be a bounded domain in R^n. Show that the problem ∆v−v^3 =0 in D; v=0 on ∂D has no solution other than v ≡ 0.

I am thinking I need to prove it to be harmonic in order to apply Green's or something, but I cannot seem to do that.

Comment: I suppose you could multiply both sides by $v$ then use the divergence theorem and the boundary conditions to get $$- \int_{D} \lvert \nabla v \rvert^{2} dx = \int_{D} v^{4} dx$$ which holds iff $v \equiv 0$ as the LHS is non-positive, the RHS non-negative.

Comment: Alternatively, use the maximum principle: if $\pm v$ had a positive maximum, then at this point we would have $\pm v^3 >0$ but $\pm \Delta v \le 0,$ contradicting the PDE.